# Ubuntu 20.04 and Docker 19.03.8 - docker removes default gateway and breaks host connectivity

Tags: networking, docker

I have ubuntu 20.04 running with a static ip.  When I first startup, I have no issues and the routes look fine:

```
# ping 4.2.2.2
PING 4.2.2.2 (4.2.2.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 4.2.2.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=15.1 ms
64 bytes from 4.2.2.2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=55 time=13.2 ms
```

```
# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp7s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     268    0        0 veth72d13a6
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     270    0        0 veth4282136
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     272    0        0 veth231344a
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     274    0        0 veth311ab6b
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     276    0        0 vethce07e31
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     278    0        0 veth634311f
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp7s0
```

However, once I start docker, the route gets modified and my default gateway removed!

```
# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     202    0        0 enp7s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     202    0        0 enp7s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     203    0        0 docker0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     204    0        0 br-eaab0b58fedb
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     205    0        0 br-1c9dab29e4e2
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     206    0        0 br-22995aab5a8d
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     280    0        0 veth5abaa22
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     282    0        0 veth20fab69
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     284    0        0 veth45e9cab
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     286    0        0 vethab5951b
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     288    0        0 vethb6baf34
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     290    0        0 veth59c9ab9
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.20.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-ea0d0b58fedb
172.21.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-229956aa5a8d
172.28.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-1c938d29e4e2
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp7s0
```

```
# ping 4.2.2.2
PING 4.2.2.2 (4.2.2.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 4.2.2.2 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1016ms
```

To resolve I can do a netplan apply, but then this breaks docker due to no routing to the containers.  I resolved to manually add the default gateway again, but this is a manual task that should not be necessary.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I was running into the same issue with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and Docker 18.09.2. `route -n` showed the same symptom. `sudo netplan apply` would bring it back temporarily.   I was able to fix it by creating `/etc/docker/daemon.json` with default-gateway set.

```
{
    "debug": true,
    "default-gateway": "192.168.1.1"
}
```

After starting docker again, the gateway address seemed to stick around and `route -n` looked good still.